# Mean comparizon of two groups - Asymptotic distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_1,\ldots,X_{n_1}\}$ and $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n_2}\}$ be sequences of independent and identically distributed random variables, such that $EX_i = \mu_X$,  $VX_i = \sigma^2<\infty$, $EY_j = \mu_Y$,  $VY_i = \sigma^2$ and $X_i$ independent of $Y_j$.

If one wants to test whether or not $\mu_X = \mu_Y$ then one of the first statistics that comes to mind is:

$$T = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{s_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}}$$
where $s_p^2 = \frac{(n_1 - 1)s_1^2 + (n_2 - 1)s_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}$.

The critical values for a test based on $T$ are usually found using the student distribution. Is this because of some asymptotic argument? What are the conditions for such approximation to be reasonable?

Comment: There is more to it than that.  Using a pooled standard deviation is done when you think the two variances are equal. The t distribution is appropriate when both populations are normal.  Of course there are conditions where the central limit theorem applies.  Then in the case of equal variances the test statistic will approach a standard normal.  Technically you need to assume a higher moment than the 2nd for the central limit theorem to hold.  When the data is non normal I see no clear reason to use the t distribution over the normal in large samples.

Comment: In addition to the nice summary by @MichaelChernick, the Wikipedia page for [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test), and the original article it cites [Welch (1947)](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13510847829341652452) may also be of interest.

Comment: Yes @GeoMatt22 Welch's test provides a frequentist approach to the Behrens - Fisher problem which has historical significance because it provided a case where Fisher's fiducial inference differed from the frequentist approach.This subject has been discussed many times on this site including some of my contributions to the discussion.